# Can you run pregen characters with only the System Reference Document?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, ogl, pregenerated-characters

The [System Reference Document](https://archive.org/details/dnd35srd) is a document containing 3.5 rules except for character creation.

Can you run pregenerated characters with only the System Reference Document?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, while that *is* the official SRD, trying to play based on those files would be miserable. I recommend trying an online, hyperlinked SRD, such as [d20srd.org](https://www.d20srd.org/index). That organizes things better, and provides links from one thing to another.

Second of all... no, you can’t play with just the SRD. The SRD isn’t supposed to replace the books, just provide a convenient way look up information quickly. Importantly, it’s missing some basic information on how to actually go about actually putting the pieces together into a character—which a pregenerated character might get you around, partially—as well as the rules for leveling up. Even with a pregenerated character, your game would be very much limited if you can’t level up.

Thirdly, even if you found the information on creating a character or leveling up online, learning to play the game from such sources would be painful. Most groups start with at least one person who has played before and can guide the rest. Without that, as well as without the guidance found in the *Player’s Handbook* and *Dungeon Master’s Guide*, you’d have a pretty hard time.

For what it’s worth, though, I did it, kind of—but my first DM was very experienced and provided a lot of assistance. I also read a lot of information online about the kind of character I wanted to play, and spent a lot of time digging around the internet for what free stuff is out there. So it’s possible—though again, without *anyone* who has played before, I think it’s going to be really hard, and even with that guidance, it’s not for everyone I suspect.